# Marks Entry using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, inline

For my university database, I have created a table (say X), which holds data as "Id, Name, Term1Marks, Term2Marks .... " some 15 fields.
I want the faculty members to enter the marks through their portal (already developed). They wish to insert marks as follows:-

```
Dropdown --> Select Branch
Dropdown --> Select Subject
Dropdown --> Select Section
```

After, this the list of Section populates as follows :-

```
Roll  Name  Term1  Term 2 ...
123  XYZ  12  22
```

Inserting marks for Term 1 specifically.
Is this possible ?
If yes , How ??

Comment: `INSERT INTO x (Term1) VALUES ("y") WHERE Roll = 123`. Something like that?

Comment: If the list of section is already populated do you want to update it? Or make a new Entry if new @SverriM.Olsen comment will work. If you want to update the field you can `UPDATE \`x\` SET \`Term1\` = 12 WHERE \`Roll\` = 123`

Comment: Yes, that is fine. But few classes have 40 students, few have 50, how do i write a general code, that automatically decides how many input fields to generate according to size of table.